# HTML Id values keep changing web scraping using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, screen-scraping, xforms

This may be a long stretch but my research has led me nowhere!

We've currently launched a new system which is web based, due to cost there are a number of letters which are based in word rather than system triggered.

I've been looking into ways that these letters can be auto-populated from scraping the web. I've been able to successfully do this using 'GetElementById'.

HOWEVER, I've since found that the ID values change for each of the customer records accessed, therefore the code I've written effectively only works with the one customer.

Using class names or any other variant does not work as only the IDs were unique enough.

Is there another way that anyone can think of? The HTML is structured as follows for a particular data item:

```
<div fieldref="PolicySummary.EffectiveDate" objectref="P379F514AC5994666A109BAB16FAF5A4F" id="f_P379F514AC5994666A109BAB16FAF5A4F8_2_1" name="f_P379F514AC5994666A109BAB16FAF5A4F8_2_1" class=" x-form-display-field">7/1/2016</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does the div element not always exist in the same place, could you not refer to it like this

```
.getElementsByClassName(" x-form-display-field")(n)
```

n being the occurrence (first = 0 second = 1 etc)

Comment: That could potentially work, whats the best way to go about including the (n) ? Might sound a silly question!

Comment: View the source code and count the number of times the class name appears, when it's on the exact div you need use that number less 1. getElementsByClassName() returns an array, so the first is key 0

Comment: Ok, so users will be using IE8 so my understanding is that getElementsByClassName is not supported by IE8 but querySelectorAll() is, would the same logic work here?

Comment: Yes indeed. querySelectorAll also returns an array of objects much the same. [See Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115(v=vs.85).aspx)